# THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial normalMap and bumpMap together?

Tags: three.js, glsl

So I know the documentation says that a bumpMap will be ignored if a normalMap is applied to a Standard/Physical material
BUT (and excuse my ignorance)
Can we not just turn off this restriction in the shader?
So we CAN have both.

I would eventually like to extend the bumpMap to have it's own repeat values so we I can have some nice tiled roughness bumps when we view the model up close
WHILE having a non repeat normalMap do it's magic

Comment: Well, there is no switch for this. Meaning you have to modify/extend the library code especially if you need different repeat setting for different textures.

Comment: .bumpMap and .normalMap basically do the same thing; a better option (in my opinion) would be to set up two normal maps with NodeMaterial, each with different scale/repeat.

Comment: Yeah I'm really impressed with the NodeMaterial, but does it support Physical material at this stage? I'm after a clearcoat as well. Don't ask for  much do I?